# How to solve $\int_0^{+\infty}\,ax\,J_0(ax)\,dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions

From some equalities I ended up with understanding that:

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\,ax\,J_0(ax)\,dx = 1$$

with $J_0(ax)$ the bessel function of the first kind and $a>0$.
But I don't know how to demonstrate it. I tried using the series representation of $J_0(ax)$, without any success!

Thanks!

$\mathbf{EDIT}$

I had to calculate the following double integral:

$$2b\int_0^{+\infty}dR\int_0^{+\infty}dk\,J_0(k\sqrt{R})\,k\,\exp(-bk^2)$$

with $b>0$. So if I first integrate in $k$, I obtain:

$$\int_0^{+\infty}dR\,\exp\left(-\frac{R}{4b}\right)=4b$$

since

$$2b\int_0^{+\infty}dk\,J_0(k\sqrt{R})\,k\,\exp(-bk^2)=\exp\left(-\frac{R}{4b}\right)$$.

Now, if I integrate first in $R$, I have:

$$2b\int_0^{+\infty}dk\,\left[\int_0^{+\infty}dRJ_0(k\sqrt{R})\right]\,k\,\exp(-bk^2)=4b$$

meaning that

$$\int_0^{+\infty}dk\,\left[\int_0^{+\infty}dRJ_0(k\sqrt{R})\right]\,k\,\exp(-bk^2)=2$$

From this it follows that $\int_0^{+\infty}dRJ_0(k\sqrt{R})\neq0$???

Comment: $J_0$ being the Bessel function of the first kind?

Comment: @user88595 yes!

Comment: Are you sure it is $xJ_{0}(ax)$ not $J_0(ax)$?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal yes..i am sure

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal How can you prove it? Where did you get the result?

Comment: @JFNJr: See my answer.

Comment: Mathematica is telling me that this integral is not convergent...?

Comment: You assume that you can switch the order of integration.  You cannot, apparently, as the integral you seek over $R$ does not converge.

Comment: @RonGordon ok. You seem to be right, but I wonder why I cannot do so.

Comment: If this is a result of a physics problem, you should suspect something is amiss.  Normally, you don't wind up with something that diverges like this.

Comment: @JFNJr: The integral does not diverge to infinity.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal ok..but it does not go to zero, apparently..so?

Comment: @JFNJr: Your integral is undefined and I already showed in my answer what's the right integrand you should use to get this equality.

Comment: @JFNJr: Note that, there is a big difference between the integral diverges to infinity and it is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is false - the integral as stated does not converge.  To see this, use the differential equation defining $y = J_0(x)$:

$$x y'' + y' + x y = 0$$

so that

$$(x y')' = -x y \implies x y' = -\int dx \, x y$$

or

$$\int dx \, x J_0(x) = x J_1(x) + C$$

or

$$a \int dx \, a x J_0(a x) = a x J_1(a x) + C$$

The RHS goes to $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

**EDIT**

As was pointed out, the above statement is not quite right.  The integral does not converge, because the RHS is oscillatory with a divergent amplitude.

Comment: Ok. Then I have some doubts in my calculations. I put the in the question as an EDIT.

Comment: @JFNJr: how did you come across that result?

Comment: now see the edited question :)

Comment: This answer is wrong! The integral in consideration does not diverge to infinity.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Ummm...aside from the fact that I just demonstrated the opposite of what you asserted, you are going to have to be a little more detailed with your contentions.

Comment: You need to do little work to see this.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: no, I do not.  YOU have to do the work for us to see this.  This is YOUR assertion, which the evidence suggests is FALSE.

Comment: @RonGordon I agree..I will wait with you.

Comment: @JFNJr: History suggests you will be waiting a very long time.

Comment: @RonGordon ahahah :D

Comment: I think what Mhenni means is that $x J_1(x)$ oscillates.

Comment: @Braindead: better.  So the integral does not converge, but the RHS does not necessarily go to inf.  OK, I see that.  Thank you.

Comment: @RonGordon What if you have $\int_0^{+\infty}\,dR\,J_0(k\sqrt{R})\cos(\omega R)$ instead of $\int_0^{+\infty}\,dR\,J_0(k\sqrt{R})$? In this case the integrals are switchable. The first here is a cosine transform (well defined if $\omega >0$). Any idea?

Comment: @JFNJr: That converges when $\omega \ne 0$.  Mathematica gives a nice simple answer.  If you post it as a question, I will derive it - if this is where you want to go.

Comment: @RonGordon I already did the calculations for the sine and cosine transform cases and I was missing the normalization factor (i.e. $\omega = 0$). I just wanted to give you an example of a switchable similar case. I still don't understand why I cannot do so. I agree with your result, but you solved somehow the indefinite integral. How could I understand that two integrations are not switchable without solving the integral itself? PS it's physics..you were right!

Comment: @JFNJr: I've seen integrals like this a million times.  And yes, I am a physicist, or at least was.  How do you see these are not switchable?  Gulp...uhhhhh...I guess you need to recognize when an integral diverges.  Spencer's answer is a very quick and dirty way to at least establish plausibility of non-convergence.

Comment: @RonGordon Ok. And $J_0(x)\cos(\omega x)$ for large $x$?

Comment: @JFNJr: that does not interest you.  What does interest you is $x J_0(a x) \cos(b x^2)$.  Which does converge for $b \ne 0$.

Comment: @RonGordon right.

Comment: @RonGordon [Which theorems' condition(s) am I not satisfying?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus)#Basic_theorems)

Comment: @JFNJr: the one that says that the integrals must individually converge in order to reverse the order of integration.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: The difference between saying that the answer diverges and doesn't converge is beside the point: the integral was simply not defined.  And I acknowledge the error I made and corrected it, rather than sweep it under the rug.  The answer is useful, and not only the OP but other people agree.  If you do not, then downvote it.  Now that I gave you far more explanation than you deserve, let me add that in my time in M.SE, I have never received such an immature, petty comment like the one you just posted.  I began my time here having a lot of respect for you, but increasingly...

Comment: ...my interactions with you have become hostile.  I would self-examine but I am far from the only one with whom you have had such negative experiences.  You want people to upvote your answer?  Start by acknowledging your mistakes, looking inward when people criticize you, and budgeting time for explaining yourself.  Instead, you treat downvotes as some conspiracy against yourself.  As a knowledgable Ph.D. mathematician, you are setting an example for young people on this site who are interested in math.  Please act the part.

Answer (score 2):

$$J_0(x) \approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos(x-\pi/4)  \quad \text{For large } x $$

The integrand is going to blow up at $\infty$ so I suspect that your integral diverges.